# How many ending does Clannad have in Visual Novel?

Tags: clannad

In the anime, Tomoya ended with one girl. But there's two ova's where he got a different ending, with two different girl.

I tried to play the visual novel once, and was able to get a good ending with Sakagami Tomoyo and Fujibayashi Kyou, but I never reach a good ending with Sagara Misae (manager of Sunohara's dorm) and Fujibayashi Ryou. How many ending are they in Visual Novel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular routes in the Visual Novel are with:

- Fujibayashi Kyou
- Fujibayashi Ryou
- Furukawa Nagisa
- Hiiragi Kappei
- Ichinose Kotomi
- Ibuki Fuko
- Miyazawa Yukine
- Sagare Misae
- Sakagami Tomoyo
- Sunohara Mei
- Toshio Koumura

There are three additional endings for the after story of the original game (therefore, routes opening up after continuing to the after story of Furukawa Nagisa). Another spin-off game is available that includes an after story for Sakagami Tomoyo, and is called "Tomoyo After: It's a Wonderful Life".

Answer (score 2):

Roel van Uden's answer is pretty accurate. However concerning Fujibayashi Ryou.

> There is no good end except for her end in Hiiragi Kappei's route.

I also found this a useful site: http://soukyuu.emevas.net/CLANNAD_guide.html

Comment: There actually _is_ a good ending for Ryou and Tomoya, other than your mentioned one.