# What are the order of clannad visual novel?

Tags: clannad

I found this in [Clannad visual novel diagram](https://vndb.org/v4/rg) website that there are a lot of side stories, partner stories and other things what are those I'm confused.So is there an order to play this games.

Comment: I guess the main game is the best to start with, then continue with prequels and sequels, and then the side stories  and shared characters. Anyway, the most logical way to play then would IMO be to play them on the release order. As long as I only played the main Clannad game, I may be wrong.

Comment: Practically speaking, you play Clannad, and then, if you want, you play Tomoyo After, which is . The rest of the things on that diagram are fanworks, aside from "Hikari Mimamoru Sakamichi", which is sort of not altogether a visual novel. Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27611/.